# Have a separate password for Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

Is it possible to have a separate password for Game Center - one that is **not** the same as I use for my Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no :-)

- If you use your Apple ID to log into Gamecenter, you *must* use the same password as for all the other places you use your Apple ID to log in.
- You can create a new Apple ID on icloud.com though and use that one for Gamecenter

Answer (score 0):

**There is a way to do this with a secondary Apple Id and it is not very convenient.**

- Logout > Sign in > Logout whenever you want to play or exit game center

Comment: Question is tagged iOS ;)

Comment: Fixed, or rather deleted :)